# Convert DataFrame string complex i to j python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this type of DataFrame I wish to utilize. But because the data i imported is using the i letter for the imaginary part of the complex number, python doesn't allow me to convert it as a float.

```
5.0 0.01511+0.0035769i
5.0298  0.015291+0.0075383i
5.0594  0.015655+0.0094534i
5.0874  0.012456+0.011908i
5.1156  0.015332+0.011174i
5.1458  0.015758+0.0095832i
```

How can I proceed to change the i to j in each row of the DataFrame?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you want to convert to float? and why do you want to change i to j? What is your goal here?

Comment: Can you show exactly what the contents of the file are (is it that text you posted?) and how you're trying to read it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string like this: `complexStr = "0.015291+0.0075383i"`, you could do:

```
complexFloat = complex(complexStr[:-1] + 'j')
```

If your data is a string like this: `str = "5.0 0.01511+0.0035769i"`, you have to separate the first part, like this:

```
number, complexStr = str.split()
complexFloat = complex(complexStr[:-1] + 'j')

>>> complexFloat
>>> (0.015291+0.0075383j)
>>> type(complexFloat)
>>> <type 'complex'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you obtain your dataframe, but if you're reading it from a text file with a suitable header, then you can use a converter function to sort out the 'j' -> 'i' so that your dtype is created properly:
For file `test.df`:

```
a    b
5.0 0.01511+0.0035769i
5.0298  0.015291+0.0075383i
5.0594  0.015655+0.0094534i
5.0874  0.012456+0.011908i
5.1156  0.015332+0.011174i
5.1458  0.015758+0.0095832i
```

the code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('test.df',delimiter='\s+',
            converters={'b': lambda v: complex(str(v.replace('i','j')))}
                  )
```

gives `df` as:

```
        a                      b
0  5.0000   (0.01511+0.0035769j)
1  5.0298  (0.015291+0.0075383j)
2  5.0594  (0.015655+0.0094534j)
3  5.0874   (0.012456+0.011908j)
4  5.1156   (0.015332+0.011174j)
5  5.1458  (0.015758+0.0095832j)
```

with column dtypes:

```
a       float64
b    complex128
```